# Split string into parts

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I want to split `NSString` into array with fixed-length parts. How can i do this?

I searched about it, but i only find componentSeparatedByString method, but nothing more. It's  also can be done manually, but is there a faster way to do this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "manual" or "not manual"? The computer is an automaton...

Comment: I can take my string,crop it and cyclically put cropped string into array. The problem is my string is very large, i need to split it into 10.000 string length parts. Totally this array will contain more then 500.000 objects. This is really huge string so i need the faster way as i know

Comment: well that magic method you are searching for does not exist. At some point, there must be a loop copying parts of your string. Even if it's not done by you, it will be somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "faster" - if it is processor performance you refer to, I'd guess that it is hard to beat `substringWithRange:`, but for robust, easy coding of a problem like this, regular expressions can actually come in quite handy.

Here's one that can be used to divide a string into 10-char chunks, allowing the last chunk to be of less than 10 chars:

```
NSString *pattern = @".{1,10}";
```

Unfortunately, the Cocoa implementation of the regex machinery is less elegant, but simple enough to use:

```
NSString *string = @"I want to split NSString into array with fixed-length parts. How can i do this?";

NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: pattern options: 0 error: &error];

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];                            
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    [result addObject: [string substringWithRange: match.range]];
}
```

Comment: Your regex matches "\n"

Answer (score 0):

Break the string into a sequence of NSRanges and then try using NSString's `substringWithRange:` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can split a string in different ways.
One way is to split by spaces(or any character):

```
NSString *string = @"Hello World Obj C is Awesome";

NSArray *words = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

You can also split at exact points in a string:

```
NSString *word = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startPoint, FIXED_LENGTH)];
```

Simply put it in a loop for a fixed length and save to Mutable Array:

```
NSMutableArray *words = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
    NSString *word = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, FIXED_LENGTH)]; //you may want to make #define
    [array addObject:word];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Notice that you'll get an exception if the range is outside of the string length, so you'll need to test for that and modify your range accordingly.

Comment: That's good. I try @Monolo 's code and it works perfectly. So i recommended to use regex ,it is suitable for my needs.