# Is there any way to split a string into multiple string based on character count (not delimiter)?

Tags: objective-c, string, split

So if I have `"7A7F6E88920AB8271A"` and I want to split it into an array of strings with same amount of character count, like `"7A", "7F", "6E", "88", ...` is there any method ready for this, or I have to manually make it on objective C? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string into parts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795440/split-string-into-parts) or [How split a string by equial parts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465420/how-split-a-string-by-equial-parts)

Comment: Please avoid asking a question without further maintaining it.
If a ducplicate question replaces your question, please remove yours to preserve SO's good quality. If an answer helped you, please upvote or accept.

Comment: @angabriel I am maintaining it. I just not open SO every hour to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an objective-c expert, but the following might lead you in the right direction (Regular Expressions)

```
NSRegularExpression regexp = [NSRegularExpression 
regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\\w){2}" 
options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 
range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

The RegExp `(\\w){2}`should find all 2-length character words and each of them are in the matches array.

Constructed from examples on this page: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsregularexpression

Comment: Regular expression, interesting! I don't know regex can be used to do that. I'll take a look and play around this for a moment and comeback here, ok? :D